# Dynamics 365 API v2: Adding sales lines to an existing sales order

Tags: web-services, odata, dynamics-365, dynamics-business-central

I am trying to add sales lines to an existing sales order using the standard API included with dynamics 365 business central. However I cannot find the correct syntax on the api request to accomplish this.

I have tried posting to the `companies({id})/salesOrderLines` endpoint, and the `companies({id})/salesOrder({id})/salesOrderLines` endpoint but no matter how I try to work my request I always get  the "Invalid Request Body" error.

Here is an example of the request I sent to the `companies({id})/salesOrderLines` endpoint:

Here is my request body:

```
[
  {
    "id": "e92c39cb-f552-4d4f-b680-ad7ded2949d0",
    "documentId": "e80573b0-9c8b-ed11-bfba-001dd8b71ee3",
    "lineType": "Item",
    "lineObjectNumber": "H10-110013",
    "quantity": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "e92c39cb-f552-4d4f-b680-ad7ded2949d0",
    "documentId": "e80573b0-9c8b-ed11-bfba-001dd8b71ee3",
    "lineType": "Item",
    "lineObjectNumber": "H10-112117",
    "quantity": 1
  }
]
```

Here is the response I get back:

> "{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Invalid Request
> Body  CorrelationId:  241e540a-5af5-4516-83f2-fbc035f80389."}}"

I am able to post a sales order and its lines simultaneously using deep requests but with larger orders they hit the request limit and I need a way of splitting up the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

salesOrderLines endpoint expects an object and does not accept collections, so best you can do here is post each line in a separate request.
Request body would look like this:

```
{
    "lineType": "Item",
    "lineObjectNumber": "H10-110013",
    "quantity": 1
}
```

id and documentId can be added to the request, but not really required.

Another option is to send the request on the $batch endpoint as described in the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/webservices/use-odata-batch

POST http://bc21-dev:7048/bc/api/v2.0/$batch

```
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "http://bc21-dev:7048/bc/api/v2.0/salesOrders(dd3585b3-dd6c-ed11-81b4-6045bd8e5172)/salesOrderLines",
            "headers": {
                "Company": "CRONUS International Ltd.",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "body": {
                "lineType": "Item",
                "lineObjectNumber": "1920-S",
                "quantity": 2,
                "unitPrice": 420.4
            }
        },
        {
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "http://bc21-dev:7048/bc/api/v2.0/salesOrders(dd3585b3-dd6c-ed11-81b4-6045bd8e5172)/salesOrderLines",
            "headers": {
                "Company": "CRONUS International Ltd.",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "body": {
                "lineType": "Item",
                "lineObjectNumber": "1952-W",
                "quantity": 1,
                "unitPrice": 183.12
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a PHP Example though the response is null

```
$items = array();

$items[] = (object)array(
    'part_no'               =>  '{PRODUCT NAME - String}',
    'product_quantity'      =>  {PRODUCT QUANTITY - Integer}
);

$items[] = (object)array(
    'part_no'               =>  '{PRODUCT NAME - String}',
    'product_quantity'      =>  {PRODUCT QUANTITY - Integer}
);

$items[] = (object)array(
    'part_no'               =>  '{PRODUCT NAME - String}',
    'product_quantity'      =>  {PRODUCT QUANTITY - Integer}
);

$requests = array();

foreach($items as $item){

    $requests[] = (object)array(
        'method'        =>  'POST',
        'url'       =>  {DYNAMICS ODATA LINK}. '(\'{COMPANY NAME}\')/Sales_Order_Line',
        'headers'       =>  (object)array(
            'Company'           =>  '{COMPANY NAME}',
            'Content-Type'      =>  'application/json',
            'If-Match'      =>  '*'
        ),
        'body'  =>  (object)array(
            'Type'          =>  'Item',
            'Document_No'       =>  {SALES ORDER NUMBER},
            'No'                =>  $item->part_no,
            'Quantity'      =>  (int)$item->product_quantity
        )
    );

}

$data = (object)array(
    'requests'      =>  $requests
);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL                 =>  {DYNAMICS ODATA BASE URI}. '/$batch',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER      =>  true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING            =>  '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS           =>  10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT             =>  0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION      =>  true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER      =>  false,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION        =>  CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST       =>  'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS          =>  json_encode($data),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER          =>  array(
        'Authorization: Basic ' .base64_encode(USERNAME. ':' .PASSWORD). '',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ),
));

$response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
$error = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```